Definition Gauge Field / Connection on principal bundle
Reading Division Algebras and Supersymmetry I by John C. Baez and John Huerta, one passage confused me a bit:

A connection $A$ on a principal $G$ bundle over $M$. Since the bundle is trivial, we think of this connection as a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 1-form.

$A$ is the gauge field of the discussed Yang-Mills theory.
I thought the definition of a gauge field was a connection on a principal bundle, which in turn is defined as a smooth $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 1-form that satisfies some other properties.
According to this passage, this does not seem to be the case. What is the correct definition? Has it something to do with local connection 1-forms?
I would be glad to be pointed to resources that define it rigorously as well. Thank you in advance!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)

@MoisheKohan, thank you for the comment, but I don't see how this answers my question: Why does this paper say we can think of the connection as a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 1-form since the bundle is trivial? Is that not true for any bundle?

If you read the definition in the link you will see that the connection form in general is defined only on the total space. For trivial bundles, one can pull-back the form from the total space to the base (using a section), this is what the article says. If the bundle is nontrivial, you do not have a section.

@MoisheKohan, I see, thank you! I thought they meant a 1-form on the total space.

Yes, I wish they were more precise on this.
